# Не правильный рендер после unshift React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

У меня в компоненте React динамически должны добавляться элементы:

```
function newElem(elem) {
    elems.unshift({
        nick: "nastya",
        text: "Бумер",
        numStory: story2,
        post: post1,
        likes: 412142,
        haveStory: false
    });
    return setElems([...elems]);
}
```

После они рендерятся:

```
<div className={"posts"} id={"posts"}>
    {elems.map((elem, i) => {
      return <Post obj={elem} key={i}/>
    })}
</div>
```

но после добавления нового компонента свойство `likes` спускается в элемент массива ниже.

Пример:

```
компонент 1
лайки: 10
  
компонент 2
лайки: 1
```

После добавления нового компонента:

```
новый компонент
лайки: 10 (хотя должно быть 412142)

компонент 1
лайки: 1
  
компонент 2
лайки: 1
```

Comment: посмотри в справке по выводу [списков](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) за что отвечает атрибут key.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! Я просто присваивал атрибуту key значение i(которое, как пишут в документации, нестабильное)

Comment: Текстовое значение более стабильное, ещё раз благодарю и sorry for this stupid question :(

Comment: @nolikk рад, что вы нашли решение вашей проблемы, но для базы знаний было бы здорово если бы был написан развернутый ответ. вы можете сделать это сами или попросить Grundy

Comment: А зачем тут вообще unshift ?

Comment: @AlexeyTen чтобы добавить элемент в начало, очевидно

Comment: А потом всё равно сделать ...elems. Хотя где эти elems определены и какой получается свйд-эффект непонятно

Comment: `return setElems([nastya, ...elems]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы используете в качестве `key` - индекс, вместо "уникального значения" и при этом делаете `unshift`, который каждый раз изменяет позицию всех элементов в массиве.

Для того что бы такого не происходило можно либо генерировать ключи в момент инициализации компонента с помощью утилит типа [uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuidv4) или брать его прямо из объекта (при наличии, например, id):

```
const elems = [
  {
    id: "hsh3k4hs"
    nick: "nastya",
    // ... остальные пары
  }
] 

<div className={"posts"} id={"posts"}>
    {elems.map(elem => {
      return <Post obj={elem} key={elem.id} />
    })}
</div>
```

*Ключи должны быть уникальными в пределах контейнера, в который производится mapping.*